# gRPC with vue js 3 not parsing a typescript object

Tags: vue.js, grpc, grpc-web

I have a simple hello world app where I am trying to parse a typescript object. Before I had done with Vue 2 class components, and I am sure the issue is the Transition to vue is just unfamiliar.

The issue with the below method is here

```
            if (response != null) {
                state.name = JSON.parse(response.getName())
                state.age = parseInt(JSON.parse(response.getAge()))
            }
```

error in console

```
Error while getting the response: TypeError: response.getName is not a function
```

Home class

```
<script lang="ts">
import {api} from "@/lib/api";
import {reactive} from "vue";

export default {
    name: "Home",
    setup() {
        const state = reactive({
            name: '',
            age: '',
            mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
            myName: process.env.VUE_APP_TITLE
        })

        const submit = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await api.getTest()
                if (response != null) {
                    state.name = JSON.parse(response.getName())
                    state.age = parseInt(JSON.parse(response.getAge()))
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('Error while getting the response:', error)
            }
        }

        return {
            ...state,
            submit
        }
    },

}
</script>
```

api.ts

```
export const api = {

    async getTest() {
        try{
            return await grpcClient.get<TestResponse>("/v1/test")
                .then(res => {
                    return res.data <-- json but would be nice if it was a TS object
                })
        }catch (err) {
            console.log("error" + err);
        }
    },

}
```

error in console:

```
Error while getting the response: TypeError: response.getName is not a function
    at eval (Home.vue?4912:19:1)
```

but even is I used

```
 state.name = JSON.parse(response).name
```

I get issues with accessing the object

My assumption was that Vue 3 had better Typescript support which is why Class components were [deprecated](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/569).

How can I get my gRPC typescripts objects intergraded with my vue components?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is I had to create a new TypeScript interface. I am not able to use the generated gRPC ones.

```js
interface Test {
  name: string;
  age: string
}
```

Axios request:

```js
async getTest() {
    try{
        return await grpcClient.get<Test>("/v1/test")
            .then(res => {
                return res.data
            })
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log("error" + err);
    }
},
```

Then to use it this:

```js
setup() {
    const state = reactive({
        username: '',
        age: '',
    })

    const submit = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await api.getTest()

            if (response != null) {
                state.username = response.name
                state.age = response.age
                console.log("I am the state " + state.username)
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error while getting the response:', error)
        }
    }

    return {
        ...state,
        submit
    }
}
```